JetBrains IDE - any way to show all modified files in the current feature branch?
I am working with Git using feature branches, and I would like to have a pane showing all the files that are modified within the current branch (new / modified and possibly deleted files). Is there any way to do this in JetBrains IDEs?
To clarify - I just want a list of files that I can open to keep editing them, not a diff. Since I already modified these files, it's likely I'll need to access them many times when working on my feature, and sometimes they are so spread out in the code base that it's difficult to find in the project pane.

THe answer should be:
Main menù -> Tool Windows -> Commits
Then select a changed file, right click on it and click on Jump to Source.

The commit pane only shows files edited in the working tree. I want a list of filed edited in the current feature branch.

Your question is not so clear. Do you want to see remote changes? I ask this because the working tree and current branch are the same thing.

I want to see a list of all files that were touched (modified / added and possibly deleted) on the current feature branch, compared to the branch it diverged from.

That is, if I checked out a feature branch and made a few commits on it, I would like to see all the files modified in all of those commits.

Yes, it is possible to view the changes on a branch in a tree view.
You can do so from the Git tool window, by right-clicking a branch, selecting the branch and then the option "Show diff with working tree". This will open the changes in a tree view.

I'm quite unsure how the other answers pointing out to something that doesn't seem to exist never the end of 2024. This exists and works perfectly! Thank you!

One possible way is to find "Project" pane and open context menu on project root. Select "Git/ Compare with Branch" and type your destination branch in the "Select Branch to Compare" dialogue that pops up.

You will get a "Changes" panel that resembles regular project view.
